# Quiz app not showing dialog in last question

Tags: java, android

So when the last question is asked on the quiz, it doesn't show the dialog box if it is correct or not. And by the results screen the last question is always considered as 'correct'

```
public class MainGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FButton buttonA, buttonB, buttonC, buttonD;
    Button pause;
    TextView questionText, triviaQuizText, timeText, resultText, coinText;
    TriviaQuizHelper triviaQuizHelper;
    TriviaQuestion currentQuestion;
    MediaPlayer mysong;

    List<TriviaQuestion> list;
    int qid = 0;
    int timeValue = 20;
    int coinValue = 0;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    Typeface tb, sb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);
        mysong = MediaPlayer.create(MainGameActivity.this,R.raw.hs);
        mysong.start();
        int media_length;

        //Initializing variables
        questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuestion);
        pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        buttonA = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
        buttonB = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
        buttonC = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonC);
        buttonD = (FButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonD);
        triviaQuizText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.triviaQuizText);
        timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText);

        resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultText);
        coinText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coinText);

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                pausedialog();
            }
        });





        //Setting typefaces for textview and buttons - this will give stylish fonts on textview and button etc
        tb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TitilliumWeb-Bold.ttf");
        sb = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/shablagooital.ttf");
        triviaQuizText.setTypeface(sb);
        questionText.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonA.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonB.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonC.setTypeface(tb);
        buttonD.setTypeface(tb);
        timeText.setTypeface(tb);
        resultText.setTypeface(sb);
        coinText.setTypeface(tb);

        //Our database helper class
        triviaQuizHelper = new TriviaQuizHelper(this);
        //Make db writable
        triviaQuizHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        //It will check if the ques,options are already added in table or not
        //If they are not added then the getAllOfTheQuestions() will return a list of size zero
        if (triviaQuizHelper.getAllOfTheQuestions().size() == 0) {
            //If not added then add the ques,options in table
            triviaQuizHelper.allQuestion();
        }

        //This will return us a list of data type TriviaQuestion
        list = triviaQuizHelper.getAllOfTheQuestions();

        //Now we gonna shuffle the elements of the list so that we will get questions randomly
        Collections.shuffle(list);

        //currentQuestion will hold the que, 4 option and ans for particular id
        currentQuestion = list.get(qid);

        //countDownTimer
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(22000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                //here you can have your logic to set text to timeText
                timeText.setText(String.valueOf(timeValue) + "\"");

                //With each iteration decrement the time by 1 sec
                timeValue -= 1;

                //This means the user is out of time so onFinished will called after this iteration
                if (timeValue == -1) {

                    //Since user is out of time setText as time up
                   // resultText.setText(getString(R.string.timeup));
                    timeUp();
                    //Since user is out of time he won't be able to click any buttons
                    //therefore we will disable all four options buttons using this method
                //    disableButton();
                }
            }

            //Now user is out of time
            public void onFinish() {
                //We will navigate him to the time up activity using below method
                //timeUp();
            }
        }.start();

        //This method will set the que and four options
        updateQueAndOptions();


    }


    public void updateQueAndOptions() {

        //This method will setText for que and options
        questionText.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
        buttonA.setText(currentQuestion.getOptA());
        buttonB.setText(currentQuestion.getOptB());
        buttonC.setText(currentQuestion.getOptC());
        buttonD.setText(currentQuestion.getOptD());


        timeValue = 20;

        //Now since the user has ans correct just reset timer back for another que- by cancel and start
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer.start();

        //set the value of coin text
        coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));
        //Now since user has ans correct increment the coinvalue
        coinValue++;

    }

    public void buttonA(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }
    public void buttonB(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }

    public void buttonC(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }

    public void buttonD(View view) {
        Button button = (Button) view;
        buttonPressed(button);
    }







    public void buttonPressed(Button button) {


        if (qid < list.size() - 1) {

            disableButton();
            if (button.getText().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
                correctDialog();
            } else {
                incorrectDialog();
                coinValue--;

            }

        } else {

            gameWon();
        }

    }









    //This method will navigate from current activity to GameWon
    public void gameWon() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameWon.class);

        intent.putExtra("score", coinValue);

        startActivity(intent);

        finish();
    }

    //This method is called when user ans is wrong
    //this method will navigate user to the activity PlayAgain
    public void gameLostPlayAgain() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayAgain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    //This method is called when time is up
    //this method will navigate user to the activity Time_Up
    public void timeUp() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Time_Up.class);
       startActivity(intent);
        finish();
   }

    //If user press home button and come in the game from memory then this
    //method will continue the timer from the previous time it left
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        mysong.getCurrentPosition();
mysong.start();
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    //When activity is destroyed then this will cancel the timer
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    //This will pause the time/

    @Override
   protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        mysong.pause();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }



    //On BackPressed
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    //This dialog is show to the user after he ans correct
    public void correctDialog() {
        final Dialog dialogCorrect = new Dialog(MainGameActivity.this);
        dialogCorrect.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (dialogCorrect.getWindow() != null) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            dialogCorrect.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
        dialogCorrect.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_correct);
        dialogCorrect.setCancelable(false);
        dialogCorrect.show();

        //Since the dialog is show to user just pause the timer in background
        onPause();
        onRestart();




        TextView correctText = (TextView) dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.correctText);
        FButton buttonNext = (FButton) dialogCorrect.findViewById(R.id.dialogNext);

        //Setting type faces
        correctText.setTypeface(sb);
        buttonNext.setTypeface(sb);

        //OnCLick listener to go next que
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //This will dismiss the dialog
                dialogCorrect.dismiss();
                //it will increment the question number
                qid++;
                //get the que and 4 option and store in the currentQuestion
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                //Now this method will set the new que and 4 options
                updateQueAndOptions();
                //reset the color of buttons back to white
                resetColor();
                //Enable button - remember we had disable them when user ans was correct in there particular button methods
                enableButton();
            }
        });
    }


    //INCORRECT//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void incorrectDialog() {
        final Dialog incorrectDialog = new Dialog(MainGameActivity.this);
        incorrectDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (incorrectDialog.getWindow() != null) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            incorrectDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
        incorrectDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_incorrect);
        incorrectDialog.setCancelable(false);
        incorrectDialog.show();

        //Since the dialog is show to user just pause the timer in background
        onPause();
        onRestart();




        TextView IncorrectText = (TextView) incorrectDialog.findViewById(R.id.IncorrectText);
        FButton buttonNext = (FButton) incorrectDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogNext);

        //Setting type faces
        IncorrectText.setTypeface(sb);
        buttonNext.setTypeface(sb);

        //OnCLick listener to go next que
        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //This will dismiss the dialog
                incorrectDialog.dismiss();
                //it will increment the question number
                qid++;
                //get the que and 4 option and store in the currentQuestion
                currentQuestion = list.get(qid);
                //Now this method will set the new que and 4 options
                updateQueAndOptions();
                //reset the color of buttons back to white
                resetColor();
                //Enable button - remember we had disable them when user ans was correct in there particular button methods
                enableButton();
            }
        });
    }













    //This method will make button color white again since our one button color was turned green
    public void resetColor() {
        buttonA.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
        buttonB.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
        buttonC.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
        buttonD.setButtonColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.white));
    }

    //This method will disable all the option button
    public void disableButton() {
        buttonA.setEnabled(false);
        buttonB.setEnabled(false);
        buttonC.setEnabled(false);
        buttonD.setEnabled(false);
    }

    //This method will all enable the option buttons
    public void enableButton() {
        buttonA.setEnabled(true);
        buttonB.setEnabled(true);
        buttonC.setEnabled(true);
        buttonD.setEnabled(true);
    }


    public void pausedialog()
    {

        final Dialog pausedialog = new Dialog(MainGameActivity.this);
        pausedialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (pausedialog.getWindow() != null) {
            ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            pausedialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
        }
        pausedialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_pause);
        pausedialog.setCancelable(false);
        pausedialog.show();



        //Since the dialog is show to user just pause the timer in background
        onPause();

        Button resume = (FButton) pausedialog.findViewById(R.id.resume);
        Button menu = (FButton) pausedialog.findViewById(R.id.menu);
        Button music = (FButton) pausedialog.findViewById(R.id.music);


        resume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //This will dismiss the dialog
                pausedialog.dismiss();
                onRestart();





            }

        });


        menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainGameActivity.this,HomeScreen.class);
                   //  mysong.release();
                    //  finish();
                startActivity(intent2);
                finish();
            }
        });






    }





}
```

EDIT: posted the full code. I tried understanding it again but I don't know what to do anymore this may be the only problem I have left other than inserting images (that's another problem for now I wanna finish this)

EDIT: I tried fixing the if statements like this:

```
      if (button.getText().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
            correctDialog();
        } else {
            incorrectDialog();
            coinValue--;

        }




        if (qid < list.size() - 1) {

            disableButton();


        } else

            {

            gameWon();
        }
```

It works now, the last answer is now also registered if right or wrong BUT the dialog box flashes for a split second and automatically goes to the results screen.

Comment: _I tried removing the '- 1'..._ Do you know at all why you do `-1`?

Comment: It's pretty hard for me to explain but I tried doing -2,-3,-4 and from what I understand putting the - always subtracts whatever total number of questions you have. from that understanding I should put '-0' or something right? but it doesn't work. If my understanding is wrong please help me clear it up.

Comment: Why is the -1 here in the first place? What happens if you put -2? Do you not get the last *two* questions? What happens if you remove the -1?

Comment: I just got the code from my other problem that just got solved. putting in -2 only gets 4 questions (questions are randomized) and it still results from the last question not having a dialog box and automatically getting a "correct" mark regardless if it was wrong.

I also tried not putting the '-' part and just getting an error.

Comment: If I had to guess, you are trying to show a dialog, but then in your gameWon() method you are doing something to interrupt the showing of the dialog.  However without more code it is hard to tell.

Comment: post more code, we need to know how `qid` is incremented.

Comment: edited and added all codes